# Converting from IEnumerable to List

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

I want to convert from `IEnumerable<Contact>` to `List<Contact>`.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 575, accepted):

You can do this very simply using LINQ.

Make sure this using is at the top of your C# file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Then use the [`ToList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToList__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) extension method.

Example:

```
IEnumerable<int> enumerable = Enumerable.Range(1, 300);
List<int> asList = enumerable.ToList();
```

Comment: It is important to note that your solution works for the generic version of `IEnumerable`. The answer from user pickles below handles the non-generic version.

Comment: I wonder if Microsoft changed this. I just tried this very example, and there is no ToList() method in IEnumerable. Using VS 2015 and .NET 4.6.1 .

Comment: @James it's an extension method. You may need the "using", but no, they did not change this.

Comment: will it throw an error if my IEnumerable is empty ?

Answer (score 226):

In case you're working with a regular old `System.Collections.IEnumerable` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` you can use `enumerable.Cast<object>().ToList()`

Answer (score 26):

If you're using an implementation of `System.Collections.IEnumerable` you can do like following to convert it to a `List`. The following uses [Enumerable.Cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) method to convert `IEnumerable` to a generic `List`.

```
// ArrayList implements IEnumerable interface
ArrayList _provinces = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
_provinces.Add("Western");
_provinces.Add("Eastern");

List<string> provinces = _provinces.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

---

If you're using Generic version `IEnumerable<T>`, The conversion is straight forward. Since both are generics, you can do like below,

```
IEnumerable<int> values = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
List<int> valueList = values.ToList();
```

But if the `IEnumerable` is null, when you try to convert it to a `List`, you'll get an `ArgumentNullException` saying Value cannot be null.

```
IEnumerable<int> values2 = null;
List<int> valueList2 = values2.ToList();
```

[image]

Therefore as mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18090667/340046), remember to do a `null` check before converting it to a `List`.

Answer (score 7):

I use an extension method for this. My extension method first checks to see if the enumeration is null and if so creates an empty list. This allows you to do a foreach on it without explicitly having to check for null.

Here is a very contrived example:

```
IEnumerable<string> stringEnumerable = null;
StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();
stringEnumerable.ToNonNullList().ForEach(str=> csv.Append(str).Append(","));
```

Here is the extension method:

```
public static List<T> ToNonNullList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> obj)
{
    return obj == null ? new List<T>() : obj.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

another way

```
List<int> list=new List<int>();

IEnumerable<int> enumerable =Enumerable.Range(1, 300);  

foreach (var item in enumerable )  
{     
  list.Add(item);  
}
```

Comment: It's quite better to use "AddRange(enumerable)" function or List(enumerable) constructor.