# Change normal loop to Parallel loop

Tags: c#, .net, parallel.foreach

I have the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   TaskExecuter.Execute();
}

class Task
{
        int _delay;
        private Task(int delay) { _delay = delay; }
        public void Execute() { Thread.Sleep(_delay); }
        public static IEnumerable GetAllTasks()
        {
            Random r = new Random(4711);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                yield return new Task(r.Next(100, 5000));
        }
 }

static class TaskExecuter
{
        public static void Execute()
        {
            foreach (Task task in Task.GetAllTasks())
            {
                 task.Execute();
            }
        }
   }
```

I need to change the loop in Execute method to paralle with multiple threads, I tried the following, but it isn't working since GetAllTasks returns IEnumerable  and not a list

```
Parallel.ForEach(Task.GetAllTasks(), task =>
{
   //Execute();
});
```

Comment: Perhaps this will help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617771/converting-from-ienumerable-to-list

Comment: @Giedrius thank you, this is right if it was an answer i would have given u 25 pts

Comment: You probably shouldn't call your class `Task`, to avoid confusion with `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Parallel.ForEach` works with `IEnumerable<T>`, so adjust your `GetAllTasks` to return `IEnumerable<Task>`.

Also .net has widely used Task class, I would avoid naming own class like that to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

[`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001.aspx) takes an `IEnumerable<TSource>`, so your code should be fine. However, you need to perform the `Execute` call on the `task` instance that is passed as parameter to your lambda statement.

```
Parallel.ForEach(Task.GetAllTasks(), task =>
{
    task.Execute();
});
```

This can also be expressed as a one-line lambda expression:

```
Parallel.ForEach(Task.GetAllTasks(), task => task.Execute());
```

<strike>There is also another subtle bug in your code that you should pay attention to. Per its internal implementation, `Parallel.ForEach` may [enumerate the elements of your sequence *in parallel*](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/parallelextensions/thread/d9121720-0fdb-4f03-8244-35f98b28aac7). However, you are calling an instance method of the `Random` class in your enumerator, which is not thread-safe, possibly leading to race issues. The easiest way to work around this would be to pre-populate your sequence as a list:</strike>

```
Parallel.ForEach(Task.GetAllTasks().ToList(), task => task.Execute());
```

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach()` may enumerate from multiple threads, *but not in parallel*. It uses locking to make sure only one thread enumerates at a time. So the usage of `Random` is fine.

Comment: @svick: You're right; I was misled by the first reply in the linked post (which was written by an established contributor). Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

This worked on my linqpad. I just renamed your `Task` class to `Work` and also returned an `IEnumerable<T>` from `GetAllTasks`:

```
class Work
{
        int _delay;
        private Work(int delay) { _delay = delay; }
        public void Execute() { Thread.Sleep(_delay); }
        public static IEnumerable<Work> GetAllTasks()
        {
            Random r = new Random(4711);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                yield return new Work(r.Next(100, 5000));
        }
 }

static class TaskExecuter
{
        public static void Execute()
        {
            foreach (Work task in Work.GetAllTasks())
            {
                 task.Execute();
            }
        }
   }
void Main()
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(Work.GetAllTasks(), new Action<Work>(task =>
{
   //Execute();
}));
}
```