# Linq IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Class>> back to List<Class>

Tags: c#, linq

How can I turn the following statement back to `List<DocumentData>`

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, DocumentData>> documents = 
                 documentCollection.Select(d => d).GroupBy(g => g.FileName);
```

the goal is to get List that should be smaller than documentCollection.
FileName contains duplicates so I want to make sure I don't have duplicate names.

I have also tried the following but it's still providing me with duplicate file names

```
documentCollection = 
    documentCollection.GroupBy(g => g.FileName).SelectMany(d => d).ToList();
```

Comment: You want to get a list of what? DocumentData?

Comment: What's the point of `Select(d => d)`?

Comment: This has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617771/converting-from-ienumerable-to-list

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Each `IGrouping<string, DocumentData>` is an `IEnumerable<DocumentData>`, so you could simply call `SelectMany` to flatten the sequences:

```
var list = documents.SelectMany(d => d).ToList();
```

**Edit**: Per the updated question, it seems like the OP wants to select just the first document for any given filename. This can be achieved by calling `First()` on each `IGrouping<string, DocumentData>` instance:

```
IEnumerable<DocumentData> documents = 
    documentCollection.GroupBy(g => g.FileName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                      .Select(g => g.First())
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: The answer addresses the OP's current question. Its shortcomings should hopefully encourage them to refine their question.

Comment: [MoreLINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/1.0.16006) has a [`DistinctBy` method](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) which is worth considering here.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't said what `T` should stand for in `List<T>` you're looking for, so here are couple the most likely to be desired:

1. `List<DocumentData>` - *rather pointless as you already have that on `documentCollection`*

   ```
   var results = documents.SelectMany(g => g).ToList();
   ```
2. `List<KeyValuePair<string, List<DocumentData>>`

   ```
   var results =
          documents.Select(g => new KeyValuePair(g.Key, g.ToList())).ToList();
   ```
3. `List<string>` - *just the names*

   ```
   var results = documents.Select(g => g.Key).ToList();
   ```
4. `List<IGrouping<string, DocumentData>>`

   ```
   var results = documents.ToList();
   ```