# Convert an IEnumerable of unknown <T> to a List

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method similar to this:

```
void Log(object value)
{
    if (value is IEnumerable && !(value is IList))
    {
        // Need to convert value to a list here
    }

    // ... Rest of code here
}
```

As the comment says, I need to check if the `value` passed in is actually an `IEnumerable` and convert it to a `List` if it is.

The problem is that the `IEnumerable`'s generic type could be anything.  Application classes, .Net Library classes, even anonymous projections via a linq select statement.

**How can I convert an `IEnumerable` (without knowing its generic type) to a `List`?**

IMPORTANT: This is using the full .Net Framework 4.x.  NOT .Net Core.

FYI: This is in legacy code.  The reason that I need to do this is because the library we use to serialize our logs (YAX) has a memory leak with `IEnumerable`s.  But we have found that if we convert to a `List` then the memory leak does not happen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting from IEnumerable to List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7617784/902497)

Comment: @RaymondChen I'm pretty sure it want as OP does not seem to know the type - their most likely need code method that let's them call `ToList<T>` without knowing type first... (unless `List<object>` is enough)

Comment: Closed as duplicate for now - Vaccano - please clarify if `List<object>` is enough (as covered in the duplicate). [edit] the question if you need something else.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - a `List<object>` is enough.  Thanks for the help.